# Integer Array of Arrays Indexing

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, integer

I'm creating large amounts of Integer[][] arrays, and need to use Integers instead of ints because I'm storing them in an ArrayList afterward. I'm getting errors when trying to access indices in this format that I wouldn't normally get if just using int[][] arrays. This is the code I'm using:

```
Integer[][] vector_xi = new Integer[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];
vector_xi[x][y] = vector_xi[x][y] + 1; \\I need to increment values in the table when events occur
```

The compiler doesn't like the above line of code, so I try initializing the values:

```
for (int j = 0; i < NUM_ROWS; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < NUM_COLS; j++) {
        vector_xi[j][k] = 0;
    }
}
```

Although it won't let me do this either. It seems that simply attempting to access the indices of the Integer[][] array I created crashes it. Does this have something to do with the Integer object? How can I get around this? Thank you for the help!

Comment: Be very specific about the "errors" you're getting. "It wont let me do this". What did "it" say?

Comment: First `for` loop declares `j`, but checks and increments `i`? *Really?* --- Second `for` loop declares and checks `k`, but increases `j`? *Really?*

Comment: Does "because I'm storing them in an ArrayList afterward" mean it is essential that the list contain references to the same `Integer` objects referenced by your array?  That seems unlikely, since the objects referenced by the array must change whenever you need to modify values.  If you don't require the same references, then you ought to be able to use an `int[][]` and copy just the *values* (as `Integer`s) to your list.

Comment: Use `int[][]` while collecting your data. The `+ 1` (or `++`) will be much faster then. Convert to `Integer` later, when you convert array to `List`.

Comment: Autoboxing can be very convenient, but one of the things it brought was a tragically reduced understanding of when to use primitives.  For the record, it's *whenever a primitive can do the job*.  Never prefer a wrapper class to a primitive type if both are viable options.

Answer (score 0):

> need to use Integers instead of ints because I'm storing them in an ArrayList afterward.

`int`s autobox into `Integer`s so this shouldn't be an issue. Just use `int[][]`:

```
 int[][] vector_xi = new int[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];
```

Also your for-loop variables look suspicious (you haven't declared `i` and you never increment `k`). It should probably look like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < NUM_ROWS; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < NUM_COLS; k++) {
        vector_xi[j][k] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course, the `for` loops become redundant when you change to `int[][]`, since they are already zero-filled.